# How to create "circles" in Box2D?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want the circle with box2d in video.
http://goo.gl/39Ff3

Comment: What have you tried? What resources have you looked at? Which part(s) are you stuck at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check [this site](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/)? There seems to be much tutorials.

And don't forget the manual especially [4.2 Circle Shapes](http://box2d.org/documentation/).

> **Circle Shapes**
>   Circle shapes have a position and radius. Circles are solid. You cannot make a hollow circle using the circle shape.
>
> ```
>    b2CircleShape circle;
>    circle.m_p.Set(2.0f, 3.0f);
>    circle.m_radius = 0.5f
> ```

Comment: Please flush out this response more or consider a comment instead.

Comment: they are useful but i want circles which has number in and acting like in video.namely the circles can't pass their in.(they can't stay the same place).

Comment: The default behavior is for shapes not to pass through each other... what is happening in your simulation? Drawing a number in them is not part of Box2D, you need to get the current position and angle and draw it yourself.

Comment: An "answer" that is just a bunch of links to pages that no longer exist isn't really an "answer"

Comment: @A.R. thank you for pointing out problems with my 5 years old answer. I hope it is now a little better.

Comment: @That's the problem with just posting links, they eventually expire.  Now your answer will last another 5 years without trouble :)