# How to draw a circular shape in PyBox2D

Tags: python, pygame, box2d

I have a code which draws a figure consisting of few polygon shapes using pyBox2D and PyGame. Ihave defined bodies and joints, it works well, it does what it is supposed to do, but problem occures when I want to change the head from polygon to circle shape, but I cannot draw it because I use for drawing vertices and circle shape has no vertices.

The problem occurs in this part of code (final drawing):

```
for body in world.bodies: #(ground_body, dynamic_body):  # or: world.bodies
    # The body gives us the position and angle of its shapes
    for fixture in body.fixtures:

        shape = fixture.shape


        vertices = [(body.transform * v) * PPM for v in shape.vertices]

        vertices = [(v[0], SCREEN_HEIGHT - v[1]) for v in vertices]

        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, colors[body.type], vertices)
```

As I said above, the problem is that box2D. b2circleShape does not have vertices. How can i draw a circle or ad vertices to that shape?
Thank you very much

EDIT: The "duplicate" does not answer my question, could you please show me how to define circular body I tried this

```
import Box2D  # The main library
# Box2D.b2 maps Box2D.b2Vec2 to vec2 (and so on)
from Box2D.b2 import (world, polygonShape, staticBody, dynamicBody, circleShape)
from Box2D import (b2FixtureDef, b2PolygonShape, b2CircleShape)

chest_body = world.CreateDynamicBody( 
        position=(10, 6.5), 
        fixtures=b2FixtureDef(
                shape=b2PolygonShape(box=(0.5, 1.5)), density=120), 
        angle=0) # This is a rectangular body which is defined correctly

circle = world.CreateDynamicBody(
    position=(10, 6.5), 
    fixtures=b2FixtureDef(
            shape=b2CircleShape(0.5), 
    angle=0)) # I tried this after checking your manual, this does not work
```

The problem may be caused (and probably is caused) by the fact that i do not know how to run IntelliSense for pyBox2D or whether there is intellisense at all. That means that I do not know which parameters are needed
Any help appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264012/how-to-create-circles-in-box2d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create "circles" in Box2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264012/how-to-create-circles-in-box2d)

Comment: Generally you have to make it without intellisense when using Python. https://github.com/pavitrakumar78/Python-Genetic-Cars-Box2D/blob/master/genetic_car_sim.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a manual for python too. Check [this](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/wiki/manual)

```py
circle = b2CircleShape(pos=(1, 2), radius=0.5)
```